# How do I hide the rEFInd boot text?

Tags: boot, boot-loader, refind

After I select an OS to boot to in rEFInd, it prints boot target and its options before booting.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the relevant option is `use_graphics_for`.  From the docs for that option:

```
# Launch specified OSes in graphics mode. By default, rEFInd switches
# to text mode and displays basic pre-launch information when launching
# all OSes except macOS. Using graphics mode can produce a more seamless
# transition, but displays no information, which can make matters
# difficult if you must debug a problem. Also, on at least one known
# computer, using graphics mode prevents a crash when using the Linux
# kernel's EFI stub loader. You can specify an empty list to boot all
# OSes in text mode.
# Valid options:
#   osx     - macOS
#   linux   - A Linux kernel with EFI stub loader
#   elilo   - The ELILO boot loader
#   grub    - The GRUB (Legacy or 2) boot loader
#   windows - Microsoft Windows
# Default value: osx
```