# How to replace rEFInd boot text with a image

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, boot-loader, refind, plymouth

I recently dual booted Arch and Windows and I've been playing around with Plymouth to try to make the boot up process more aesthetic and I found a really nice theme but rEFInd's boot up text ruins it by appearing before the theme loads and then after it before loading my lightdm login.

I already took a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272318/how-do-i-hide-the-refind-boot-text) and I followed the answer and it works. The text no longer appears. However, instead there's a weird blackish screen that replaces it and my theme is still ruined. Is there anyway to remove this and just show my theme? The plymouth theme is [dark-arch](https://github.com/jsayol/plymouth-theme-dark-arch)  if that makes a difference. I can post any needed config files or anything else too, don't  know what's needed though.

Thanks for any help!